# Computer cannot detect hard disk

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, motherboard

Details:

- BIOS: AMI Bios, set primary master to Auto
- OS: Windows XP Sp2
- Memory: 384 Mb
- Processor: Pentium 3

yeah this one is really very old. And some of the capacitors in the motherboard are already bulging. 
It detected the hdd yesterday when were trying to fix it and install xp. But today it cannot boot and said: Boot failure. 
What can you suggest that I would do to revive this old machine.
What would be the problem, is it the hdd, the ide cable or the motherboard.

Comment: Or all of them, maybe? RIP.

Comment: I should think that Pentium 3 era motherboards are not in much demand these days. If you look around your community you could probably find one to use ... if that's what you think you really want to do. Look on either a local swap board (freecycle?) or electronic disposal sites. 

But I can't but say that I think it's time to move on. Even if you get a P3 system working they are a power inefficient way to get anything done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the caps are bulging, you certainly have a motherboard problem and any work you put into it will be wasted shortly. Unless you have a spare P3 motherboard kicking around, your time is probably best spent elsewhere.

It should be easy enough to see if the HDD is bad as well, you can just plug it into another machine. There's no way to properly diagnose any other component when you have them connected to a faulty motherboard.